# Cannot draw specific graphs in Latex for my math homework

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphs

Can anyone tell me how to draw this graph (and these types of graphs) in latex? Thanks [image: Graph]

Comment: This is fairly easy to do using tikz by just defining the six points, drawing between them etc. There are many example online as to how one uses tikz

Comment: I am sorry I am very new to this! Can you send me a link! @daleif

Comment: You can also play with https://www.mathcha.io/editor .

Answer (score 2):

Here is something to play with. I ordered the nodes differently, you can change that your self. I'm not going to explain the steps in this example, please see the tikz manual instead.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (a1) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (a2) at ($(a1)+(0:3cm)$);
  \coordinate (a3) at ($(a1)+(60:3cm)$);
  \coordinate (move) at (4,1);
  \coordinate (b1) at ($(a1)+(move)$);
  \coordinate (b2) at ($(a2)+(move)$);
  \coordinate (b3) at ($(a3)+(move)$);

  \draw (a1) -- (a2) -- (a3) -- cycle;
  \draw (b1) -- (b2) -- (b3) -- cycle; 

  \draw (a1) to [bend left] (b1);
  \draw (a2) to [bend right] (b2);
  \draw (a3) to [bend left] (b3);

  \fill (a1) circle (1pt) node[left] {$v_1$};
  \fill (a2) circle (1pt) node[below] {$v_2$};
  \fill (a3) circle (1pt) node[left] {$v_3$};
  \fill (b1) circle (1pt) node[below] {$v_1'$};
  \fill (b2) circle (1pt) node[right] {$v_2'$};
  \fill (b3) circle (1pt) node[right] {$v_3'$};

  \node at ($(a1)!0.5!(b2)+(0,-1.5)$) {$G_1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A rather short code with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-0.5,-0.5)(5,3)
\psset{PosAngleA=90,PosAngleB=-90,PosAngleC=-90}
\pstTriangle(1,1.7){v_1}(0,0){v_2}(2,0){v_3}
\pstTriangle[PointNameA=v^\prime_1, PointNameB=v^\prime_2, PointNameC=v^\prime_3] (3.6,2.5){u_1}(2.6,0.8){u_2}(4.6,0.8){u_3}
\foreach \s/\t in {v_1/u_1, v_2/u_2, u_3/v_3}{\ncarc[arcangle=40]{\s}{\t}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `multido` is not needed.  `\foreach` is in `pgffor` that is automatically loaded by PSTricks.

Comment: @LetMeBeYourLostDisciple: You're right. It is a remnant from an initial try, that  I finally didn't use because  the special configuration made things a bit more complicated than with \foreach. I removed it from the code.

Answer (score 1):

The `graphs` library can make this rather short.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, quotes}
\begin{document}
\tikz[label position=below, bend angle=15]\graph[
  nodes={fill, draw, circle, inner sep=+.1em},
  simple, empty nodes, counterclockwise=3]{
  { [cycle] 1 ["$v _1$" above], 2 ["$v _2$"], 3 ["$v _3$"] }
  --[bend left]
  { [cycle, /tikz/shift=(15:4), radius=+0cm]
            1'["$v'_1$" above], 2'["$v'_2$"], 3'["$v'_3$"] },
  3 --[bend right] 3'
};
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]