# Adding label to tikz nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a graph defined as follows. The real thing has hundreds of nodes, this is just an example. How can I add a label (rotated x degrees) on top of a node?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}
\framesubtitle{Subtitle}

\tikz [>=stealth, black!50, text=black, very thin,
    every new ->/.style = {shorten >=1pt},
    graphs/every graph/.style = {edges=rounded corners},
    hv path/.style = {to path={-| (\tikztotarget)}},
    vh path/.style = {to path={|- (\tikztotarget)}},
    t/.style = {
      circle, minimum size=1mm, thin, draw=black!80, scale=0.1, fill=black!80},
    shape = coordinate
    ]
    \graph [grow left sep=1.5mm, branch down=1.0mm, simple] {
        
t0/""[t]
 -- {
  t1/""[t]
   -- {
     t17/""[t],
     t18/""[t]
   }
 };
 };
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Off topic: Instead of using `""` with every node, you can just say [`empty nodes`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-graphs#tikz/graphs/empty:nodes) as part of the graphs options. And similar, you can say [`nodes=t`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-graphs#tikz/graphs/nodes).

Comment: On topic: you can use [`label`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#tikz/label) with the graphs nodes, as well, say `label={[rotate=90, anchor=west]north:Hello World}`. You can of course set `every label/.style={rotate=90, anchor=west}, label position=north` then that can be shortened to `label=Hello World`. With the `quotes` library loaded, you can even use `"Hello World"` as part of the nodes' options. If you want to use the graph's nodes' name or text instead of `Hello World`, this can be done with a bit of work, as well.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Does `label` actually work with this code?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, Off-topic #1: I don't understand `empty nodes` and `nodes=t`. Can you please give an example with a bit of context around it? Off-topic #2: I tried `t0/""[t, label={[rotate=90, anchor=west]north:Hello World}]`, there is no label in the output.

Comment: @AlanMunn It worked with another answer but there seems to be a [clash with the `babel` library](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/669671/good-way-to-place-node-text-next-to-node-tikz-library-graphs/669711#comment1664660_669711) I have already forgotten about. Don't know how this would factor in here, though. I will have to check what's going on. You can always place labels later and in the old way: `\node also[label=Hello World](t0);`. But let's hope we don't have to resort to that. Checking my own answers we can find [more working examples](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/694115).

Comment: Oh, wait a minute. What's that `shape = coordinate` doing there? This will turn every node into a coordinate (unless otherwise specified like with `circle` in `t`) thereby gobbling the text and any visual output of a node. (And a label ist just another node.)

Comment: Removing `shape=coordinate` does it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use TikZ's own [`label` key](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#tikz/label) to add additional nodes to those that make up the graph.

You can just add these to the options of each node, say

```
t0/""[t, label={[rotate=90, anchor=west]north:Hello World}]
```

If all labels will look the same, it makes sense to set the `every label` key to the needed settings.

You will have to make enough space between the graph's nodes since the `graphs` library will not take the labels into account. If an automatic approach is needed here, we will need to invest a bit more work.

---

If the labels content corresponds to the nodes' names (`t0`, `t1`, …) or the nodes' text, you can use `\tikzgraphnodename` and/or `\tikzgraphnodetext` as part of the label's text.

---

Since `shape = coordinate` sets the shape for all nodes unless otherwise specified you will have to either remove it or set `rectangle`/`shape = rectangle` explicitly for the labels. I've opted for the former since I don't see the benefit for setting all nodes to coordinates.

### Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}
\framesubtitle{Subtitle}
\tikz[
  black!50, text=black, very thin,
  every new ->/.style = {shorten >=1pt},
  graphs/every graph/.style = {edges=rounded corners},
  hv path/.style = {to path={-| (\tikztotarget)}},
  vh path/.style = {to path={|- (\tikztotarget)}},
  every label/.style={
    rotate=90, label position=north, anchor=west, 
    node font=\footnotesize, inner sep=+.15em,
  },
  t/.style = {
    circle, minimum size=1mm, inner sep=+0pt,
    thin, draw=black!80, fill=black!80},
%  shape = coordinate % don't do this or add rectangle to every label
]\graph[
  grow left sep=1em, branch down sep=1.3em, simple,
  empty nodes, nodes={t, label={\tikzgraphnodetext}},
] {
  0 -- {
    1 -- {
      17,
      18/Hi
    }
  }
};
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]